# I'm trying to make a transparent non-fixed navbar in Angular 9 using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, angular, sass, bootstrap-4

My navbar is transparent but i dont want it to scroll with the rest of the page, I want it to be NON-FIXED. However it's only when the navbar is not transparent it stops scrolling with the page. Like when i set the position to relative in scss, the background becomes white and the navbar is Non-Fixed, but i want it transparent and non-fixed

header.component.html

```
<!--menu-->
<header>


  <!-- As a heading -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
  </nav>

</header>


<!-- routes will be rendered here -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>





header.component.scss
    .navbar{
  background-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  font-family: "Uni-Sans";
}
.navbar{    
  position:absolute  !important;//this makes navbar not have a white background
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by **NON-FIXED**? You don't want your navbar to scroll along with the rest of the page but you also don't want it to be fixed at a particular position? Sounds contrasting to me.

Comment: i dont want my navbar to scroll with the page